# Adding variable value on onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `table` and i am adding new row through `javascript` and adding an `event` on new row as well but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```js
function moreitem() {
  document.getElementById('tottr').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('tottr').value) + 1;
  ain = document.getElementById('tottr').value;
  $('#mytable tbody tr:last')
    .after("<tr><td><select name='pid[]' id='' class='form-control' onchange='getstock(this.value,'st" + ain + "','pc" + ain + "')'><option value=''>Select Product</option><option value='1'>Drink</option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='st" + ain + "'  placeholder='Available Stock' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text' id='qty" + ain + "' onchange='gettot(this.value,ain)' name='qty[]' placeholder='Quantity' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text' id='pc" + ain + "'  name='pprice[]' placeholder='Per Piece Price' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text'  name='tprice[]' placeholder='Total Price' id='tp" + ain + "' class='form-control'></td></tr>");
}

function getstock(inval, stid, pcid) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "getprice.php",
    data: "inval=" + inval + "&stid=" + stid + "&pcid=" + pcid,
    type: "post",
    success: function(e) {
      // alert(e);
      $('#hide').html(e);
    }
  })
  // alert(inval);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Qty.</th>
      <th>Amount Per Piece</th>
      <th>Total Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr1">
      <td>
        <select name="pid[]" id="" class="form-control" onchange="getstock(this.value,'st1','pc1')">
          <option value="1">hello</option>
          <option value="2">Hello2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" id="st1" placeholder="Available Stock" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="qty1" onchange="gettot(this.value,1)" name="qty[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="pc1" name="pprice[]" placeholder="Per Piece Price" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tprice[]" placeholder="Total Price" id="tp1" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <a href="#" onclick="moreitem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add More Item</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="tottr" value="1">
```

`getstock` is working for the `first row` but not for other rows and when i `inspect` the select `dropdown` it shows below:

```
onchange="getstock(this.value," st2','pc2')'="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do so messy while using parameterize function with html string. 
make it simple and pass it to function.

something like below

```
 var stvar="st"+ain;
  var pcvar="pc"+ain;
```

```js
var ain = 1

function moreitem() {
    document.getElementById('tottr').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('tottr').value) + 1;
    ain = document.getElementById('tottr').value;
    var stvar = "st" + ain;
    var pcvar = "pc" + ain;
    $('#mytable tbody tr:last').after("<tr><td><select name='pid[]' id='sel_"+ain+"' class='form-control'><option value=''>Select Product</option><option value='1'>Drink</option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='st" + ain + "'  placeholder='Available Stock' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text' id='qty" + ain + "' onchange='gettot(this.value,ain)' name='qty[]' placeholder='Quantity' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text' id='pc" + ain + "'  name='pprice[]' placeholder='Per Piece Price' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text'  name='tprice[]' placeholder='Total Price' id='tp" + ain + "' class='form-control'></td></tr>");
    $("#sel_"+ain).on("change",function(){
        getstock($(this).val(), stvar, pcvar) 
    })
}

function getstock(v, s, p) {
    console.log(v)
    console.log(s)
    console.log(p)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Qty.</th>
            <th>Amount Per Piece</th>
            <th>Total Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr1">
            <td>
                <select name="pid[]" id="" class="form-control" onchange="getstock(this.value,'st1','pc1')">
                    <option value="1">hello</option>
                    <option value="2">Hello2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="st1" placeholder="Available Stock" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="qty1" onchange="gettot(this.value,1)" name="qty[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="pc1" name="pprice[]" placeholder="Per Piece Price" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tprice[]" placeholder="Total Price" id="tp1" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <a href="#" onclick="moreitem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add More Item</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="tottr" value="1">
```

Comment: But it's passing st  and pc as object and i want to pass as string

Comment: Your answer is producing onchange="getstock(this.value,st2,pc2)" but i want getstock(this.value,'st2','pc2')

Answer (score 0):

I think the single quote before getstock and before st2 gets confused. You can escape and print double quotes for onchange event so that the inside single quote and outside double quotes doesn't get confused. I hope the below code helps.

```js
function moreitem(){        document.getElementById('tottr').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('tottr').value)+1;
  ain=document.getElementById('tottr').value;
  $('#mytable tbody tr:last').after("<tr><td><select name='pid[]' id='' class='form-control' onchange=\"getstock(this.value,'st"+ain+"','pc"+ain+"')\"><option value=''>Select Product</option><option value='1'>Drink</option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='st"+ain+"'  placeholder='Available Stock' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text' id='qty"+ain+"' onchange='gettot(this.value,ain)' name='qty[]' placeholder='Quantity' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text' id='pc"+ain+"'  name='pprice[]' placeholder='Per Piece Price' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='text'  name='tprice[]' placeholder='Total Price' id='tp"+ain+"' class='form-control'></td></tr>");
}

 function getstock(inval,stid,pcid){
  $.ajax({
   url:"getprice.php",
   data:"inval="+inval+"&stid="+stid+"&pcid="+pcid,
   type:"post",
   success:function(e){
    // alert(e);
    $('#hide').html(e);
   }
  })
  // alert(inval);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Qty.</th>
    <th>Amount Per Piece</th>
    <th>Total Amount</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr id="tr1">
    <td>
     <select name="pid[]" id="" class="form-control" onchange="getstock(this.value,'st1','pc1')">
      <option value="1">hello</option>
            <option value="2">Hello2</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="st1"  placeholder="Available Stock" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="qty1" onchange="gettot(this.value,1)" name="qty[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="pc1"  name="pprice[]" placeholder="Per Piece Price" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="tprice[]" placeholder="Total Price" id="tp1" class="form-control"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   
   <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
     <a href="#" onclick="moreitem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add More Item</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
<input type="hidden" id="tottr" value="1">
```